# How do I enable EVP functions in openssl?

Tags: linux, openssl, heartbleed-bug

I am trying to update my web server to the latest openssl with the heartbleed patch ( 1.0.1g ). I grabbed the tarball from openssl.org. Said the usual `./configure; make; make install`.
Had to say `config shared` to get it to make the .so file ( by default it only generates the .a ).   Updated the link in /usr/lib64 to point to the new .so -

Now httpd fails to run with the following complaint:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1: undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc
```

`nm -g | grep idea` says: `U EVP_idea_cbc`

... so it knows about the symbol, but the symbol is undefined.

Openssl documentation says that they disable IDEA by default, because of a patent ( which apparently expired in 2012 ).  They go into great detail on how to disable it, but not on how to enable it.  Furthermore, they say it's disabled by default.

Apache httpd demands the symbol, and will not start without it.

I have tried saying "config shared enable-idea" and the config script is happy, but the symbol is still undefined after the build.  I piped the build output into a file, and the crypto/idea files ARE being compiled.

EVERY symbol starting in `EVP_*` is undefined... They are also undefined in `libssl.a`... So maybe I'm barking up the wrong IDEA tree?

So my question becomes - how do I enable these `EVP_*` symbols?

Comment: Have you looked at [the FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site? Your question is off-topic here, it seems...

Comment: I would say it's on topic.  It's about network security, webapp security and crypto.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved it.  The problem was simple.  These symbols are indeed undefined in `libssl.so` (or `.a`).  They are actually defined in `libcrypto.so`.  I wasn't getting the new `libcrypto.so` because....

...The new openssl tarball installs its outputs by default in `/usr/local/ssl`.  This is configurable, but it really wants to install ALL the ssl stuff (including the libs) in `/something/something/ssl`.  So you have `/something/something/ssl/lib`, `/something/something/ssl/bin` etc.

So when I said `make install`, it created `/usr/local/ssl` with all the good stuff in it.  I
made a symbolic link in `/usr/lib64 from openssl.so.1.0.0 -> /usr/local/etc/ssl/lib/openssl.so.1.0.0.`  But I did not realize that I needed to do the same for `libcrypto.so`, so that still had the old stuff.

So I was using the new `libssl.so`, and an old `libcrypto.so`.  Bad mojo.

Comment: You have to be careful of installing your version of OpenSSL over top of your distribution's version of OpenSSL. Usually, you create your own package that supersedes your distro's version of the package. Here's how you do it in Ubuntu: [Override Distro Package with Custom Package?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/395280/override-distro-package-with-custom-package). Sorry, but I don't know how to do it in Slackware.