# Unable to load shared object openssl.so

Tags: r

I'm getting an error related with openssl.so when I run the following.

```
.libPaths()
# [1] "/home/karthiaru/anaconda/lib/R/library"    
library(googlesheets)
gs_auth()
```

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :    unable to load
> shared object
> '/home/karthiaru/anaconda/lib/R/library/openssl/libs/openssl.so':
> /home/karthiaru/anaconda/lib/R/library/openssl/libs/../../../../libssl.so.1.0.0:
> undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc

There is a openssl.so file in the path.
[image: openssl.so]

Tried to install openssl based on another stackoverflow post - [OpenSSL installation and "openssl.so loading failed ... execution halted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885223/openssl-installation-and-openssl-so-loading-failed-execution-halted). But got the following error

> Configuration failed because openssl was not found. Try installing:
>
> - deb: libssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
> - rpm: openssl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
> - csw: libssl_dev (Solaris)
> - brew: openssl@1.1 (Mac OSX)
>
> If openssl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a openssl.pc file.
>
> If pkg-config is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via: R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
>
> /home/karthiaru/anaconda/lib/R/bin/config: 1: eval: make: not found
>
> ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘openssl’

**Environment**

- Ubuntu: 16.04 x64
- R: Conda R 3.3.2

How do I resolve this?

Comment: As suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016514/how-do-i-enable-evp-functions-in-openssl, do you have `libcrypto.so` in the same directory? If not, make it available there, restart R, and try again.